# Help me identify the model of this Cannondale frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, cannondale

[image]I tried everything, saw many catalogues and also tried with the serial numbers but still nothing.

[image: this is the serial code I think. From what I can read I see it's BNRB300131 and the other code P21547] this is the serial code I think. From what I can read I see it's BNRB300131 and the other code is P21547

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. There's a guide on asking such questions, have you seen it? https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: That's a start, do you have any more information/pictures of the bike, badges, components? You can't tell much for sure other than it probably is 2000s (?) MTB from Cannondale, judging by this shot. And even if: What do you need the information for? I doubt that it is a model you can sell for big money and if it is about replacing components, most of them are (industry-)standard ones and can be swapped out without detail knowledge about the bike itself (brakes, drivetrain, bearings, wheels/tires, ...)

Comment: I also have the serial number, but it doesn't help at all. It's early 2000 from what I understand, especially from the logo you find in the front. It's an MTB. I was just curious. If I sold it, since I renovated almost all parts, apart from the frame, I wouldn't go over 250-300 euros. By the way I have no intention to sell it, but I've never seen this frame in any catalogue from 2000 to nowadays. I added an image of the serial number on the bike and some more photos, if you need me to take images of a specific part/angle, let me know.

Comment: Have you checked https://vintagecannondale.com/catalog/ for various years? Looks like it could be a F-series bike, the cable routing on the top tube can be rather seen on older models (late 90s to early 2000s) but I haven't seen any exact match...

Comment: I've looked almost all the catalogues and I can tell from the logo on the front it must be early 2000s, but still have no clue, I could try to check again but the F-series models

Comment: The serial number (prefix *P*) indicates it is a 2004 model (that's consistent with the 2000+ logo) - according to this [page](https://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/). I find the tube shapes pretty characteristic, but I didn't see any matching model in the the 2004/05 catalogues. Is there really no model name on the whole bike?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem, I didn't find any tube frame, which makes suspect that it may not be a Cannondale. No model name on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it is a Cannondale.
Here's why:

1. It has a downtube decal on both the down tube and the top tube. Companies are very picky about branding and this is not how Cannondale labels it's bikes. Someone may have removed the original stickers and purchased Cannondale stickers for some creative branding. Search for "gold Cannondale frame stickers" to see examples.
2. It has a WAG Bike suspension fork
3. It's difficult to see but it looks like the crank is all steel. Steel riveted chain rings for sure and it looks like steel crank arms. Cranks like this are typical of department store bikes.
4. Cannondale did make some frames with square tubing chain stays but I can't find anything with as much square tubing as this frame.

One way to prove it's not a Cannondale is to show that it's really something else.
I have been searching for any mountain bike that matches and am having trouble finding a frame with this much square tubing. I'll keep searching and maybe someone else can help confirm or disprove my theory.

Comment: + The wields also look like s**t.

Comment: the WAG bike suspension fork was added by me later, but the original one was with "cannondale" sticker too (actually it looks like it's printed on it). I actually modified almost everything apart from that frame. It's all new, I also changed the handles today. By the way, I think you're right, it could be a reproduction based on some model from Cannondale, but it's not cannondale. everything is aluminium though. I'm going crazy trying to understand what this frame is, because I'm also seeing other brands too. Those serial codes don't help at all.

Comment: I changed the suspension, because the old one wasn't working the way it was supposed to anymore and took another one which is actually better, it's aluminium too and it allows you to enable/disable suspension and set it lighter or heavier